# Где и как хранятся переменные из области видимости функции

Tags: javascript

Разбираюсь с областью видимости в JS. Есть такой код:

```js
function createCounter() {
    var numberOfCalls = 0;
    return function() {
        return ++numberOfCalls;
    }
}
var fn = createCounter();
console.log(fn()); //1
console.log(fn()); //2
console.log(fn()); //3
```

Непонятно, где хранится переменная `numberOfCalls`. Понятно, что в области функции `createCounter`. Но каким образом область сохраняется после выполнения функции? И где хранится эта область?

Comment: Блин, ну ты возвращаешь в функции значение этой самой переменной. А потом значение этой переменной передаётся в переменную `var fn` — в эту переменную записывается результат возврата функции.

Comment: Как  к ней доступ получить   к этой переменной ?

Comment: Никак. Это называется замыкание, читайте

Comment: мне вот тоже интересно ведь я недавно делал функцию и в ней при каждом вызове создавалась переменная со значением 0. почему тут сохраняется?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/closures

Comment: @Horchynskyi Ну так при *каждом* же вызове. Тут `createCounter()` вызывается всего *1* раз ) Возвращает уже другую функцию, которая затем уже вызывается.

Comment: @Alexander Igorevich, как один если мы консолью 3 раза вызываем?

Comment: Как я понимаю .  сохроняеться  сылка на переменную.   и при каждом запросе он  обрашаеться  к этой переменной numberOfCalls.  только как к этой  переменной на примую обратиться.  уверен есть возможность.

Comment: @AmirOFF определись, ты что спрашиваешь `каким образом область сохраняется после выполнения функции? И где хранится эта область?` или `только как к этой переменной на примую обратиться` ? это разные вопросы, требующие разных ответов и объяснений и более того второго вопрос требует взаимный вопрос: "зачем тебе это?"... хотя ответ на второй вопрос скорее никак, чем что-то еще (тут всё зависит...)

Answer (score 0):

Могу ошибаться, но это не очень похоже на замыкание.
В зависимсоти от места появления функция может быть:

`function createCounter()` объявлением функции или

`var fn = function createCounter()` именованной функцией выражением

Согласно спецификации ECMAScript именованная функция-выражение связывает код с переменной fn а не с функцией createCounter() 
Формальная разница между безымянной и именованной функцией-выражением состоит в том, что последняя связывает своё имя с локальной переменной внутри функции. Это может быть использовано для написания рекурсивных функций (как в вашем примере).

Comment: fosh4455 -Могу ошибаться, но это не очень похоже на замыкание. Пологая на что вы так пишите.
Понятно что  функция замыкается  т е  есть внутрення функция у которой есть сылка  как понимаю поэтому функцию называют функцией замыкания. но не суть . суть  вопроса в том как получить доступ к этой переменной .  неужели нужно  писать контрукций для получения .

Comment: @AmirOFF я передумал, это замыкание )) https://learn.javascript.ru/closures а хранится она в LexicalEnvironment который в fn а т.к. ссылка на переменную есть в function() то она не очищается сборщиком мусора между запусками

Comment: Есть  понимание как получить   доступ к ней ?  и как бы с вами я мог в лс пообщаться:?

Comment: @AmirOFF думаю fn.numberOfCalls или createCounter.numberOfCalls да я нуб, что со мной общаться? )) Если что в https://vk.com/id281610803

Comment: @AmirOFF, _Есть понимание как получить доступ к ней?_ - доступ возможно только _внутри_ замыкания, снаружи эта переменная никак не доступна.

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался  с замыканием классная штука